Construction of skew-Specht modules, and whether it’s directly generalized from constructing Specht modules
In terms of (complex) representations of symmetric groups. I know Specht modules, and I know there is an isomorphism between the ring of symmetric polynomials and representations of symmetric groups.
My question is, I want to find the image of the skew-Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda/\mu}$ under the isomorphism said above (I don’t know whether it’s called skew-Specht modules), like I know the image of Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda}$ is the Specht module $V_{\lambda}$, I wonder whether the image $V_{\lambda/\mu}$ of $s_{\lambda /\mu}$ is exactly defined the same way as we define Specht modules.
Namely, is it  $\mathbb{C}[S_{d}]\,a_{\lambda/\mu}\,b_{\lambda /\mu}$ where we fix a standard tableaux $T$ of skew-shape $\lambda/\mu$, where $|\lambda /\mu| = d$,
$$
\begin{aligned} 
a_{\lambda/\mu} &= \sum_{g: \text{ g fixes rows of T}} g, \\[6pt]
b_{\lambda/\mu} &= \sum_{g: \text{ g fixes columns of T}} \operatorname{sgn}(g)\,g. 
\end{aligned}
$$
If so how can I prove this is the image?

There may be a simpler way, but we can prove that this module also decomposes using Littlewood-Richardson coefficients (James, The representation theory of the symmetric group)

How can I directly construct an isomorphism $\oplus \mathbb{C}[S_{d}]c_{\nu}^{\oplus C_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda}} \cong \mathbb{C}[S_{d}]c_{\lambda /\mu}$?

In the book of James, he uses a tool called $\textit{picture}$ to produce such an isomorphism. But it is not that easy, as he spends 2 chapters constructing it (it has been a long time since I read it so I can't give you an outline of the proof, maybe someone here will be able to do so! But I recommend this book if you want the details)

Thank you! I will look into it. @eti902

The skew Specht modules can indeed be defined in the way you suggested. And they do indeed decompose into the straight ones via the Littlewood-Richardson rule -- a direct sum decomposition in characteristic $0$, or a "Specht series" (a filtration with subquotients isomorphic to straight Specht modules) in general. See Michael Clausen, Multivariate polynomials, standard tableaux, and representations of symmetric groups, 1991 for a self-contained (but not exactly simple) proof.

Thank you I just saw your reply and just began to read the reference you sent. And a similar question, when I was searching result of my question I saw an expression containing Littlewood-Richardson coefficient too. Do you also happen to know how to construct an isomorphism $V_{\mu}•V_{\nu} \cong \oplus V_{\lambda}^{\oplus C_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda}}$ too? @darijgrinberg

Yes -- this follows from the above decomposition of a skew Specht module. Indeed, it is not hard to construct an isomorphism from $V_\mu \bullet V_\nu$ to the skew Specht module of the shape obtained by connecting the Young diagrams of $\mu$ and $\nu$ diagonally. (Essentially, the tableaux of the latter skew shape can be decomposed into a tableau of shape $\mu$, a tableau of shape $\nu$, and a way to shuffle their values. The shuffling corresponds to the induction from $S_k \times S_{n-k}$ to $S_n$ inherent in the definition of $\bullet$. I don't know where this is written up.)

I see. Thanks a lot @darijgrinberg

Just thought of this, there is also $\text{Res}{S{n} \times S_{d}}^{S_{n+d}}V_{\lambda} \cong \oplus_{\mu,\nu} (V_{\mu} \otimes V_{\nu})^{\oplus C_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda}}$. Similar idea? @darijgrinberg

This one is simpler; you can filter the restriction with Specht modules as subquotients. The analogous claim for Schur functors (i.e., representations of GL rather than of symmetric groups) is Proposition (2.3.1) in Jerzy M. Weyman, Cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies, CUP 2003, but I assume there is a better reference.

Thank you again @darijgrinberg

Here is a direct description: for a skew partition $\lambda \setminus \mu$ of $n$ (where $\lambda$ is a partition of $m+n$ and $\mu$ is a partition of $m$), the skew Specht module $S^{\lambda \setminus \mu}$ is the multiplicity space
$$S^{\lambda \setminus \mu}=\mathrm{Hom}_{S_m}(S^\mu,\mathrm{Res}^{S_{m+n}}_{S_m}(S^\lambda)),$$ which is of course not an irreducible $S_n$-module in general (though it is irreducible over the graded affine Hecke algebra $H_n$ of the symmetric group, via the surjection from $H_n$ to the centralizer algebra of $S_m$ in $\mathbf{C} S_{m+n}$). As mentioned in the comments, there are a number of combinatorial rules including the Littlewood-Richardson rule computing the decomposition of this representation in to irreducible $S_n$-submodules, and it follows from the material in chapter 1 of Macdonald's amazing book Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials that the Frobenius character of this module is the skew Schur function.

Thank you, sorry for the late reply I just saw it, I will read the book you mentioned. But first, why $S^{\lambda /\mu}=\text{Hom}{S{m}}(S^{\mu}, \text{Res}{S{m}}^{S_{m+n}}(S^{\lambda}))$? Do you construct an isomorphism to that direct sum of specht modules, or by what method?

@W.Yu I would say that $S^{\lambda \setminus \mu}$ can be defined in multiple ways, the most natural of which is the definition I give in my answer above. It is then a theorem (which follows from tensor-hom adjunction and the material in section 7 of chapter 1 of Macdonald's book) that its Frobenius character is the skew Schur function.

I see, thank you @Stephen

I am curious, is it possible to construct an isomorphism from the skew module you gave to the direct sum directly? Such isomorphism exists but it’s better we can construct one. @Stephen

@W.Yu It is possible to construct an isomorphism from multiplicity space definition above and the definition in terms of idempotents you gave, but to get from either of those to the definition involving Littlewood-Richardson numbers inevitably results in a proof of the Littlewood-Richardson rule (or at the least, a combinatorial formula for the LR numbers...) so I doubt that a very explicit construction of such an isomorphism can be found.
